# GDB: Is there a command that allows you to see how many times a function has been called?

Tags: c, gdb

I am currently having to write implementations of malloc() and free(), and am given a driver program that will run my two implementations.

But currently, I am segfaulting because free() is trying to free a payload size that is well in the billions of bytes (which is wrong). I have the line and line number from running GDB, but I need to know if malloc() and free() have been called more than once, to confirm that there is indeed *at least one* case where it runs smoothly.

Comment: Well, I guess I could create a global variable in the program as a counter... and then print that in GDB. But is there a better method?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

(gdb) help break
Set breakpoint at specified line or function.
break [LOCATION] [thread THREADNUM] [if CONDITION]
LOCATION may be a line number, function name, or "*" and an address.
If a line number is specified, break at start of code for that line.
If a function is specified, break at start of code for that function.
If an address is specified, break at that exact address.
With no LOCATION, uses current execution address of selected stack frame.
This is useful for breaking on return to a stack frame.

Comment: The documentation of `break` is really good at documenting `break` but is not enough in this case :) . Martin's answer is the one that tells you how to see the hit count kept by GDB

Answer (score 21):

First set a breakpoint for malloc and free. Afterwards use the "ignore" command with a high value to suppress really stopping at those breakpoints. GDB will still count how many times the breakpoints have been hit. When you call "info breakpoints", GDB will show you these counts.

Answer (score 19):

Just to complete the information of Martin, run gdb and then, on the gdb prompt:

```
b <file:line_number or function name>
ignore <breakpoint identifier> 100000
```

Then you run your executable (or you resume) and then, when you want to check the number of times the breakpoint has been hit, on the gdb prompt:

```
info breakpoints
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want deactivate the "ignore" use the command `ignore <breakpoint identifier> 0`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for a conditional breakpoint, where you can filter out calls that exceed your size threshold. Use the `if (condition)` clause in `break`.

Another option on linux is to use `perf` to set a probe and capture arguments. See `perf probe` for details. This lets you instrument the binary non-intrusively and trace all calls. `perf script` is good for outputting the results.